# Web Scraping with BeautifulSoup and Urllib2 using proxies

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, urllib2, proxies

I am trying to crawl a website with a proxie but I'm getting Errors. I'm still learning, so your input will be greatly helpfull.

This is my code:

```
hdr = {
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Connection": "keep-alive" 
    }
proxies = {'http': 'http://user:pass@us-wa.proxymesh.com:11111', 'https': 'http://user:pass@us-wa.proxymesh.com:11111'}
try:
    page = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(urltocrawl_b,headers=hdr,proxies=proxies), timeout=7),'lxml')
except :
    print "-----------------ERROR  ---------------------"
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'proxies'
```

Thank you !!

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/22967185/6066986

Comment: If I take out the proxy, it works perfectly fine. Like this:

hdr = {
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Connection": "keep-alive" 
    }
page = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(urltocrawl_b,headers=hdr), timeout=7),'lxml')

Comment: @AlexandreFenyo, I've added the error. Thanks!