# python urllib.request timeout error on a resource my browser can access

Tags: python, python-3.x, screen-scraping, urllib

A script I use for scraping stock ticker changes from nasdaq.com has stopped working.

The url can still be accessed by my browsers, but gives a timeout `TimeoutError: [WinError 10060]` error when I attempt to access it using Python 3 urllib.request.

Other url's are still behaving as expected.  I'm trying to understand whether this is some server-side script that is detecting I'm not in a browser?  I am providing spoofed headers.  See below.

```
import urllib.request
import traceback

req_headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
    }

urls=['http://msn.com',
      'https://google.com',
      'https://www.nasdaq.com/markets/stocks/symbol-change-history.aspx?sortby=EFFECTIVE&page=1',
      'https://yahoo.com']
for url in urls:
    try:
        req = urllib.request.Request(
            url,
            data=None,
            headers=req_headers
        )
        print('trying %s'%url)
        pagetext=urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
        print ('Success',len(pagetext))
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
```

The outputs are as follows:

```
trying http://msn.com
Success 446035
trying https://google.com
Sucess 234077
trying https://www.nasdaq.com/markets/stocks/symbol-change-history.aspx?sortby=EFFECTIVE&page=1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
trying https://yahoo.com
Success 642758
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I get "200 OK" from the nasdaq.com url with your code.

Comment: Can you increase the timeout value maybe ?

Comment: Interesting.  I just tried a timeout of 25s and now the nasdaq url fails with `[WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`  Maybe I've become blacklisted?  Odd given that I just ping that resource once per day.  I will explore further

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue using a proxyhandler as in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22967084/urllib-request-urlretrieve-with-proxy

Comment: It could be the time between two requests to Nasdaq. What is the average time between two requests? Could you once check changing the user agent too?