# how can we make our scraping to look like a real person browsing

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So, I am scraping a website but every now and then I will get temp-banned for some minutes. I am using headers in my code for scraping but I was wondering if is there is any more stuff we can do to look like a real person rather than just a bot.

I researched a bit and found out that we can make our **scraping a little slower** as well to bypass detection.

I'd want to hear your thoughts and suggestions.

```
ua=UserAgent()
   hdr = {'User-Agent': ua.random,
  'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
  'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
  'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
  'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
```

*(Had to put this code because it wasn't letting me post it!)*

Comment: Most probably they have saved your IP.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/fake-headers/

Answer (score 2):

One of the things you can do it's to make your time.sleep random. Bots are pace keeping and humans are erratics.

You need to import random library

```
   import random
```

Then you change your time.sleep for something like this:

```
  time.sleep(random.randint(3,15))
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid being banned is to not blast the site with so much force cause then they will definitely take not because a human using a browser will not be able to hit the site with so much speed hence it must be a bot. So going a little slower on the number of requests you send per second helps. Another way you can get around this is by using proxies. If you get banned for sometime it means they have taken note of your IP address and blocked it. If you are using proxies when they block one IP you can switch over to another and continue on your merry scraping way, this is one of the major components of more complex bots and spiders and it is something that is not too difficult to do.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def crawler():
   headers = {headers}
   proxies = {proxies}
   url = url
   requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
```

with this your IP address is hidden. All proxy addresses do not work in all locations, so what i tend to do when working with them is have a bunch of them in a file somewhere. I read the file and loop through the proxies i get from the file until i get one that works in my present location, then scraping can begin without the fear of my IP getting blocked.  check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464799/how-to-add-proxies-to-beautifulsoup-crawler) if still in doubt about how proxies work with requests library and beautiful soup

Comment: i usually use JSON files to store most of my proxies that work in various locations, that way i do not have to hard code them myself i can just read them out of the JSON file, convert them to python dictionary and make use of them in my code as shown